# Closedness in subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(E,\tau)$ be a topological space, $\Omega\in\tau$ and $$\left.\tau\right|_\Omega=\left\{O\cap\Omega:O\in\tau\right\}$$ denote the subspace topology on $\Omega$ inherited from $\tau$. Since $\Omega\in\tau$, it's easy to see that $$\left.\tau\right|_\Omega=\left\{O\subseteq\Omega:O\in\tau\right\}\tag1.$$

> By $(1)$, a subset of $\Omega$ is $\left.\tau\right|_\Omega$-open if and only if it is $\tau$-open. But does the analogue result hold for "open" replaced by "closed"?

I thought this should clearly be true, but it seems like it is not. Let $C\subseteq\Omega$ be $\left.\tau\right|_\Omega$-closed. Then, by $(1)$, $O:=\Omega\setminus C$ is $\tau$-open. However, $$E\setminus C=\underbrace{\Omega\setminus C}_{\:=O}\cup\underbrace{(E\setminus\Omega)\setminus C)}_{=\:E\setminus\Omega}=O\cup E\setminus\Omega\tag2$$ is not necessarily $\tau$-open, since $E\setminus\Omega$ is $\tau$-closed. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement does not hold if you replace by "closed". Take as counter-example $(E, \tau) := (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $\Omega = (0,1)$. Then $(0,1/2]$ is $\tau \vert_{\Omega}$-closed, but it is not $\tau$-closed.

However, the statement is true if $\Omega$ is $\tau$-closed. Can you show this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was asking this question, because I wondered about the following: If $A\subseteq\Omega$, do the closures of $A$ with respect to $\left.\tau\right|_\Omega$ and $\tau$ differ or coincide? I guess they differ, which should be clear from taking $A=\Omega$.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, unless $\Omega$ is closed, they may differ.

Comment: I'm confused, from [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2508097/47771), $A\subset\Omega$ is $\left.\tau\right|_\Omega$-compact if and only if $A$ is $\tau$-compact. Isn't this a contradiction to your answer, since at least in a Hausdorff space compactness implies closedness?

Comment: Yes, this is true for compact sets, but not for just closed ones (closed does not imply compact). Try seeing what goes wrong in the example I gave in my answer: $(0,1/2]$ is closed in $\Omega$ but it is not compact (neither in $\Omega$ nor in $\mathbb{R}$)